# Not Able to delete/ format my Micro SD

Tags: format, micro-sd-card

I tried almost all the options to format my Micro SD

First the Basic Option.

Then tried the SD Formatter and it showed that the SD card is write protected.

And then I searched on youtube to remove the write protection 
and got some videos to remove the write protection option from Command "CMD" and tried that too.

It's not yet solved.

I tried to delete each file/folder but once i reconnect the deleted files comes back and i tried to right click on the files and changed from readonly and applied but still it goes back to readonly without any error.

Comment: I'm afraid your screenshots are broken.

Comment: Sounds like the firmware has triggered write-only mode. Get what you need from it then bin it & buy another. They're not worth fighting once they start to play up.

Comment: @Tetsujin: you mean read-only?  Write-only memory is only useful for saving spam email.  :-)

Comment: oops, d'oh, yes… sorry ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You must have an adapter which is a little bigger than the sd card itself. The sd card goes into it. the adapter has a switch to its side. If you flip the switch up, this disables the write protection. If it is flipped down write protection will be enabled. In your case its probably down so just put your sd card in and flip it up.